# How do I gain the attention of a person of higher rank?

Tags: communication, conflict

I’m currently involved in a group that is supposed to test bugs and give feedback about a game. We are called the Quality Assurers. We’ve been giving feedback about the current state of the game and we suggested a few ideas, however the developers remained silent. They only speak/interact with us if we’re giving feedback about the upcoming update. We have updates release every week.

I’d like to know how to get their attention without annoying them. We communicate through discord and the developers do not like being tagged so i dont know how to get their attention without giving them a bad impression of me and the rest of the group. There are a lot of feedback that require the developer's opinion, yet it is lacking. The only thing I fear is getting kicked from the quality assurance group if I try to tag one of the developers.
There is a community manager that i can contact though. I can tell her about this ongoing issue. However, I will only be doing that if I have no other choice.
Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Most places have some sort of application where the QA testers report bugs and the devs have to fix them (or explain why they shouldn't be fixed)or the product can't go to Production.

Comment: @HLGEM The current system I'm working with is just like you described. That's not the issue here though. It's the feedback about game mechanics, how unbalanced things are and solutions to it- they get ignored. Only ones that is noticed is those that touch on the upcoming update.

Comment: Speaking to the manager should rarely / never be your last resort - managing includes helping you deal with problems you can't or don't know how to deal with yourself. Although it's not clear why you actually want to speak to the developers, or what that would accomplish - it seems like your place is just to report on the quality and let them deal with that feedback in whichever way they see fit (if they never deal with **any** issues reported, that might raise the question of whether they look at the feedback at all, but other than that I wouldn't say you should expect individual feedback).

Comment: "Current state of the game" - are you talking about the design and play of the game, as opposed to coding bugs and performance of the software? Like "I think Duke Nukem should be wearing a tank top" types of issues? Then that would probably, I believe, be outside your area of responsibility.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you would be kicked from QA when you would provide proper feedback. If the developers like to live in a sandbox, that's their problem. You are trying to help them and they are making it very difficult for you to do your job properly (right now you can only find issues that need fixing, but apparently can't get them to the developers). Tag the developers regardless. You're not being a dick to them.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Yes, I am talking about the design and play of the game. I believe that is in my area of responsibility as a QA member, however, I will be double checking with the community manager if it is. The QA team consists of players who regularly play the game, and the developers don't really play the game so I think it's best if it is our responsibilty to give feedback.

Comment: Okay. I think, usually, most people think of the QA function in software development in a slightly different light. Could be a broader term for evaluating game play, though. That's why I asked. To me, I'd think QA is more "is it doing what it is supposed to be doing" where game play is more "what do we want it to be doing" which is more a design-phase consideration, possibly. But I know little to nothing about game development and improvement.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts I myself dont understand why the developers **hate** being tagged. There's a rule where we are absolutely *not* allowed to tag developers unless there is a very game breaking issue (major bugs like duplication glitches etc). And that is why I may get kicked. Also the developers usually act like theyve had a bad day so we have difficulty trying to discuss things with them. Even the CM admits to having trouble talking with the developers. I enjoy the game and the community so I am staying as a QA member and maybe possibly make things change for the better.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I see what you mean. I myself have no previous experience in game development and I thought joining the QA team of a game I love would give me an opportunity to further my experience.

Comment: I'm curious, and the answer changes my answer to your question, are you all working for a company which is developing a game or is this more of an open-source/hobby situation?  If its a company, I would expect there to be a defined process for feedback to the developers, if not, there are other approaches I would suggest.

Comment: "Communicate through discord" -- do you literally mean [discord](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discord) (strife, quarreling) or is this a typo for [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/), a community forum software?

Comment: @bluegreen It's sort of like a company but not to an extent. The staff team, which includes Moderators, Admins, Head Admins, and QAs all do voluntary work.

Comment: @shoover Discord is a social media platform. You can organise text and voice channels appropriately, it's neat and easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encourage you to compile a short list of the most important feedback topics that you felt got ignored. Then go to you manager and ask if there is a way for you to improve the feedback-process. (Don´t go complaining, but with a positive attitude!)

It may be that certain topics are ignored because they are scheduled for a later date, or the dev´s already got their own solutions they want to try next. May also be that management does not want you to waste time on those topics, because they are paying somebody else for this job. May also be that you feedback is welcome, but needs another form of communication. Be open-minded and see what your manager thinks about this.

Comment: " May also be that management does not want you to waste time on those topics, because they are paying somebody else for this job." As far as I'm aware, there is no one else responsible for giving feedback about the game. The other options you have mentioned sounds like it can "solve" this ongoing issue. Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome :) there may also be other reasons, just wanted to say: talk about it, but be open!

Answer (score 4):

Talk to the community manager.  Explain your need to contact developers and what issues you're facing and then take the resulting advice.  Discuss as required.

It seems as though being the interface between you and the developers is part of the CMs job.

Comment: +1 for talk to the manager. It may be that interacting with the devs is not your job. If you give your feedback and hear nothing back, your manager may be happy with that and not require any more of you.

Comment: @DavidK the thing is, we have a specific text channel meant for feedback. They only reply to those that talk about the upcoming update. I will still talk to the CM though, I guess I have no other choice. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @user8872 While I obviously like this answer, I usually recommend waiting at least 24hrs before accepting. This question has only been posted on this site a few minutes, and you don't want to discourage other people from answering.

Comment: @DavidK Good idea. I considered it too but I thought "Why not?". Im getting the hang of this :D

Answer (score 1):

I asked if what you were referring to was a job or more of a community based project.  If it were a job, you would have more leverage because, I assume, there would be an established process and ramifications if its not followed.

Since its more of a volunteer I have a couple of different suggestions.  We software developers tend to not like people criticizing our work, which makes it difficult for many new developers since so much of the job involves exactly what you are saying, feedback from testing...as well as code reviews, etc.  My suggestion would be to pick out a developer or two and try to find something in common with them...develop a personal relationship/friendship.  If you are more than a screen name/email address they are more likely to listen to you.   Also, if you come can across as knowledgeable about development rather than just "X doesn't work right", "Y looks bad", etc you have a better shot at gaining their respect.

Personally, I would try to discuss issues directly with developers (not suggesting you bypass the formal process of bug reports, etc), because my experience from a developers standpoint is talking to the person reporting a problem is much more useful than relying on a printed write up or communication via managers both of which usually result in twisted information.

I am a little confused by terminology you used.   My experience is that QA tend to be interested in things like Are you following the process?, have you created all the documents, are you following the coding standards?, Are all the requirements met, etc. whereas there is usually a different test team which runs the software and verifies it is working correctly.  It's conceivable that a small project would combine these, but be sure you aren't overstepping your responsibility.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try developing friendships with the developers (lol). Also, I'm pretty sure I'm not doing more than I should be.

Comment: @user8872 I didn't mean to suggest you were overstepping, I just wanted to be sure based on terminology.   Names, titles, job descriptions, tend to mean very little in the software industry.